# WPF update TreeView when source updates for a tree model

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I implemented a tree model like this:

```
public class Node
{

    public NodeValue Item { get; set; }

    public Node Parent { get; set; }

    public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

And I displayed this nodes in a WPF TreeView.

```
 <TreeView Name="MainTreeview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItemChanged="MainTreeview_SelectedItemChanged" >
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local2:Node}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <TreeViewItem  Header="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TreeView>
```

My problem is that I cannot update view after I update the model. I don't understand from other articles how to update the UI, because they are too complex.
Now, I know that are 2 possible ways:

1. Using dependency properties: I understood how they work but I don't know how to apply them to my model.
2. Using Event triggers but I also don't know how to apply them to my problem.

Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply have your node implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and use [ObservableCollections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of non-obserable Lists.

Partial implementation to get you on your way...

```
public class Node : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Node _parent;
    public Node Parent 
    {
        get
        {
            return this._parent;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this._parent)
            {
                this._parent= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Node> Children { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Node>()

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Comment: To make the implementation of this even easier, get [PropertyChanged from Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) (also available via NuGet) and add `[PropertyChanged.ImplementPropertyChanged]` before your class definition (`public class Node()`)